# Как записать значения в базу данных postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

В строке запроса ввожу команду `insert` для таблицы `Applicants`.
[image: Таблица]

Для каждого столбца необходимо добавить по одному значению.

```
INSERT INTO public."Applicants"(
    "Id_applic", "Surname", "Name", "Patronymic", "Citizenship", "Score", "DateOfBirth", "PhoneNumber", "Enrollment_date")
    VALUES (1, 'Ivanovich', 'Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'Russia', 3.7, '12/17/1997', '8966443377', '12/17/1997');
```

После запуска, появляется ошибка `ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибочный литерал массива: "Ivanovich"`.

Пробовал записать значения все вместе и каждый отдельный в фигурные скобки, но появлялась ошибка `ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "{")`.

Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Вместо массива символов `character[]` используйте тип `varchar`.

Comment: а ещё лучше `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема разрешилась сменой типа данных `character[]` на `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что char[30] подразумевает вставку 30 символов. Я бы сменил тип данных столбца на varchar, но если необходимо его оставить, тогда бы преобразовывал строки к нужному типу данных перед вставкой: cast('Ivanovich' as char(30))